# Loading image from Bytes into Texture2D generates low quality results

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm using Unity and using an `Image` object to display an image by loading its bytes (coming from a JSON request) in a `Texture2D` object, but the resulting image is blurry and pixelated, in a very low quality. This is the code:

```
Texture2D myTexture = new Texture2D(2, 2, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);
myTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
myTexture.LoadImage(Bytes);
myImage.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = myTexture;
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Any idea on how to improve the quality on this? There should be a way to make it look better, if I import an asset into Unity (image) and set it with filter mode `Point`, it actually looks pretty good, but in this case, it just makes it worse. The original image is pretty detailed:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with image exact **width and hight** in

Texture2D myTexture = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);

or

Texture2D myTexture = new Texture2D(1, 1, TextureFormat.ARGB32, false);